# Oracle query optimization help (involves TRUNC)

Tags: oracle, date, query-optimization

Here is the query. 
closed_ts is a timestamp column. What I am trying to do is, find out how many were "closed" today, this month, this year and this week. Is there a better way to do this?

```
select table_id,
  case
    when trunc(closed_ts) = trunc(SYSDATE, 'DD') then 1
    else 0
  end as day_count,
  case
    when trunc(closed_ts) >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM') then 1
    else 0
  end as month_count,
 case
   when trunc(closed_ts) >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') then 1
   else 0
 end as year_count,
 case
   when trunc(closed_ts) >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'IW') then 1
   else 0
 end as week_count
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would want to aggregate the values with a sum() around each case statement and group by table_id, but since you asked about query optimization...

If there is an index on closed_ts you won't be able to use it because you are trunc'ing it.  Truncating the closed_ts date is unnecessary since you are checking whether it is strictly larger than day, week, month, year, so this query will definitely result in a full table scan.

I'd likely rewrite it without the trunc whether there was an index on closed_ts or not:

```
select table_id
      ,sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as day_count
      ,sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(sysdate,'MM') then 1 else 0 end) as month_count
      ,sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(sysdate,'YYYY') then 1 else 0 end) as year_count
      ,sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(sysdate,'IW') then 1 else 0 end) as week_count
 from myTable
group by table_id
```

btw: table_id sounds like a primary or surrogate key - are you sure you want it in the results?

Comment: There is no where clause, whether there is an index on closed_ts or not is irrelevant

Comment: I am summing and grouping. I just didn't include it in my original query for brevity. We do have index on closed_ts. I'll try the >= without trunc(closed_ts). Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Pop an index on (closed_ts,table_id), and apply a predicate on closed_ts as below ...

```
 select
   table_id,
   sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(SYSDATE,'DD'  ) then 1 end) day_count,
   sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(SYSDATE,'MM'  ) then 1 end) month_count,
   sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(SYSDATE,'YYYY') then 1 end) year_count,
   sum(case when closed_ts >= trunc(SYSDATE,'IW'  ) then 1 end) week_count,
 from
   myTable
 where
   closed_ts >= least(trunc(SYSDATE,'YYYY'),trunc(SYSDATE,'IW'))
 group by
   table_id
```

As user1842757 mentioned, lose the trunc on the closed_ts. You can also lose the ELSE 0 in the case statements